# How to replace text in AST (ANTLR) with C#

Tags: c#, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

Can anyone help me with this problem. I need to traverse an Abstract Syntax Tree to replace all the Children's Text in C#

Answer (score 1):

I would say the [`CommonTree.Text`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/blob/48aec80520/runtime/CSharp3/Sources/Antlr3.Runtime/Tree/CommonTree.cs#L172) property is provided for that purpose, but as you can see the method literally does nothing. The [`CommonTreeAdaptor.SetText`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/blob/48aec80520/runtime/CSharp3/Sources/Antlr3.Runtime/Tree/BaseTreeAdaptor.cs#L303) method (inherited from `BaseTreeAdaptor` at least throws a `NotSupportedException`.

What you need to do is get the `IToken` associated with the tree node, probably by calling [`CommonTreeAdaptor.GetToken`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/blob/48aec80520/runtime/CSharp3/Sources/Antlr3.Runtime/Tree/CommonTreeAdaptor.cs). You can then set the [`IToken.Text`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/blob/48aec80520/runtime/CSharp3/Sources/Antlr3.Runtime/IToken.cs#L42) property of the token, which at least for [`CommonToken` is implemented](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/blob/48aec80520/runtime/CSharp3/Sources/Antlr3.Runtime/CommonToken.cs#L124).